# Array ? Como resolver

Tags: php, array, if

Existe este site que estou montando onde fiz uma junção de um código que inserção de marca d'água com um formulário onde seria possível optar qual marca seria sobreposta à imagem que foi dada upload. Como estou aprendendo o PHP ainda, tive que fazer na mão, opção por opção. Como posso resumir todo este código ? Além disso, é possível também que o próprio script que insere o .png sob a foto insira um sobre o outro até chegar no resultado final ao envés de ter que criar cada opção de .png com todas as opção de marcas d'água ?

Para ilustrar melhor, aqui o site que estou fazendo:
http://ilhas.16mb.com

E este é o código fonte:

```
<script src="http://deepliquid.com/Jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />

<?php

        $S = isset($_POST['salvador']);
        $B = isset($_POST['brisas']);
        $P = isset($_POST['pontes']);
        $V = isset($_POST['porto_velho']);

        if($S && !$B && !$P && !$V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/salvador.png";
        } elseif ($B && !$S && !$P && !$V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/brisas.png";
        } elseif ($P && !$S && !$B && !$V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/pontes.png";
        } elseif ($V && !$S && !$B && !$P) {
            $image_path = "avatares/portovelho.png";
        } elseif ($S && $P && !$B && !$V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/salvador_pontes.png";
        } elseif ($S && $V && !$B && !$P) {
            $image_path = "avatares/salvador_portovelho.png";
        } elseif ($B && $V && !$S && !$P) {
            $image_path = "avatares/brisas_portovelho.png";
        } elseif ($B && $P && !$S && !$V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/brisas_pontes.png";
        } elseif ($S && $P && $V && !$B) {
            $image_path = "avatares/salvador_pontes_portovelho.png";
        } elseif ($B && $P && $V && !$S) {
            $image_path = "avatares/brisas_pontes_portovelho.png";
        } elseif ($S && $B && $P && $V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/todos.png";
        } elseif ($S && $B && !$P && !$V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/salvador_brisas.png";
        } elseif ($S && $B && $V && !$P) {
            $image_path = "avatares/todos_sem_pontes.png";
        } elseif ($S && $B && $P && !$V) {
            $image_path = "avatares/todos_sem_portovelho.png";
        } else {
            $image_path = "avatares/ilhas.png";
        }

function watermark_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    global $image_path;
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = $height = 800;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
    list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);        
    $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
    $pos_y = $height - $w_height;
    imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 100);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}

$demo_image= "";
if(isset($_POST['createmark']) and $_POST['createmark'] == "Submit"){
    $path = "uploads/";
    $valid_formats = array("jpg","bmp","jpeg");
    $name = $_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
    if(strlen($name))
{
   list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
   if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)&& $_FILES['imgfile']['size'] <= 10*256*1024)
    {
    $upload_status = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'], $path.$_FILES['imgfile']['name']);
    if($upload_status){
        $new_name = $path.time().".jpg";
        if(watermark_image($path.$_FILES['imgfile']['name'], $new_name))
                $demo_image = $new_name;

    }
    }
    else
    $msg = "A foto tem que ter menos que 2,5mb.";
    }
}

    # Conta quantos arquivos existem na pasta de upload
    $diretorio = scandir("uploads/");
    $qtd = count($diretorio) - 2;





?>


    <html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Avatarizador</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="avatar.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="conteudo">
            <form name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                <h1>Avatarizador !</h1>
                <div class="giro">V 2.0</div>
                <p class="texto">Já foram criadas <strong><?PHP echo ("$qtd"); ?></strong> fotos com o avatar do EREA Ilhas.</p>

                <input style="margin-bottom:15px;" type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" />

                <p>Selo dos próximos encontros:</p>
                <!-- <p style="font-size:9pt;">Lembre que o EREA Salvador está concorrendo com o EREA Brisas, então escolhe apenas um deles ;)</p> -->
                <br>

                <input type="checkbox" name="salvador" value="on">
                <label class="texto">EREA Salvador 2017</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="brisas" value="on">
                <label class="texto">EREA Brisas 2017</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="pontes" value="on">
                <label class="texto">EREA Pontes 2016</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="porto_velho" value="on">
                <label class="texto">EREA Porto Velho 2016</label>

                <br>

                <input type="submit" name="createmark" id="createmark" value="Submit" />

                <br>
                <?php
                    if(!empty($demo_image)){
                        echo '
                            <center>
                                <b>Click na imagem para fazer o download.</b>
                                <br><br>
                                <a href="'.$demo_image.'" download>
                                <img id="avatar" src="'.$demo_image.'" />
                                </a>
                            </center>
                            ';

                        # Salva dados em txt com o nome da foto para que possa ser rastreado quem criou o arquivo (avatar)
                        $arquivo = "rastro.txt"; /* Lembrar de mudar a permissão do .txt para 777 */
                        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia'); # Sao_Paulo para usar horário de Brasília (Não esqueça do horário de verão)
                        $data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
                        $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
                        $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");   
                        fwrite($fp,"Arquivo: $new_name | Data: $data | IP: $ip | Navegador: $browser \n\r");   
                        fclose($fp);

                    }
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: O problema é somente este "seletor"?

Comment: Isso Inkeliz, eu não sei como fazer isso de forma resumida. Se precisar fazer alguma alteração retirando algo ou adicionando algo, tenho que refazer tudo um a um

Comment: Eu sei um método fácil, mas não sei  se é o melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Por lógica os nomes estão com um padrão, então, renomeie alguns ficando assim:

Crie um arquivo "separado" e apenas altere true e false para verificar como iria funcionar, é mais fácil.

```
<?php

$S = isset($_POST['salvador']);
$B = isset($_POST['brisas']);
$P = isset($_POST['pontes']);
$V = isset($_POST['porto_velho']);

if($S){$NomeAux[] = 'salvador';} // se tiver S tem salvador    
if($B){$NomeAux[] = 'brisas';} // se tiver B tem brisas    
if($P){$NomeAux[] = 'pontes';} // se tiver P tem pontes    
if($V){$NomeAux[] = 'portovelho';} // se tiver V tem portovelho   

$image_path = 'ilhas'; // para não bugar (:    

if(isset($NomeAux)){  // ****** Se tiver algum selecionado!    
    foreach($NomeAux as $nome){  // irá usar todos os nomes que possuem true    
        $image_path  .= $nome.'_';     
        // irá junta-los -> exemplo: salvador_ ou salvador_brisas_    
    }
}

// resulta nisto:    
$image_path = 'avatares/' . trim($image_path, '_') . '.png'; //***  Isto deve ser mantido, agora  está com o nome da variavel que utiliza!

// Remove a ultima _ adicioando e adicione o caminho.    
?>
```

**Nota IMPORTANTE:**

Altere o `todos_sem_portovelho.png` para `salvador_brisas_pontes.png`

Altere o `todos_sem_pontes.png` para `salvador_brisas_portovelho.png`

Altere o `todos.png` para `salvador_brisas_pontes_portovelho`

Teste [isto](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2cdc731822215c3031457c39ba5672756825681f).

Comment: Quando vc diz para alterar o true, seria no value do input (checkbox) ?

Comment: Exato. Nada muda.    $S = isset($_POST['salvador'])  (...) terá o valor equivalente ao TRUE e FALSE, só substituir. Apenas optei por deixar TRUE e FALSE para que possa verificar mais fácil. :)

Comment: Verifique a modificação. O isset() irá setar como "true" se existir e "false" se não existir, por isso coloquei diretamente "true" e "false". Agora está mais claro o que quis dizer.

Comment: Estou tendo estes erros
http://prntscr.com/9nt2xl

Comment: Acho que faltou adaptar algumas coisas. É fácil corrigir. Crie um isset($NomeAux) antes do foreach e MANTENHA o "'avatares/'.     trim($image_path, '_').     '.png'" caso contrario não irá achar o arquivo. Vou editar novamente, marcando onde foi alterado.

Comment: Fiz uma nova alteração

Comment: Acho que agora não há nenhum problema. Irei melhorar a formulação nas próximas respostas. :S Tenho preguiça de ficar devido várias variáveis.

Comment: Cara, vc já está ajudando imensamente :D

Os erros sumiram, mas não consegui obter a imagem final com as marcas d'água, acredito que estou errando em adaptar alguma coisa aqui, mas continuo tentando

Comment: Dica de quem também aprendeu PHP na tentativa e erro (sem curso, sem nada): dê um var_dump($image_path) isso irá mostrar o que  esta variável está segurando. Veja se ela é a mesma que tinha definido no código  anterior (aquele manual).

Comment: Inkeliz, script funcionando perfeitamente ! Só a questão do nome de cada .png que ficou chatinho kkkk, pq vou ter que criar sempre na ordem que a pessoa selecionar, estilo: ilhas_salvador_brisas_pontes
mas se eu não selecionar "brisas", terei que criar outro .png com o nome "ilhas_salvador_pontes"

De qualquer forma, ajudou muito cara :)

Comment: É este é o inconveniente. Não sei como está usando (e qual biblioteca/classe). Talvez seja possível fazer o seguinte: junta a imagem de ilhas + salvador (salva!) + brisas e salva (assim terá 3 juntos) e carregue. Eu utilizei um sistema similar num site e sempre que tentava 'ir somando' sem salvar ele não funcionava, com era um site de teste deixei por isso mesmo. Para otimização não é bom fazer isso sempre a cada requisição. É ideal que uma vez que já exista utiliza-lo, daí cria uma variável (se isto já existe use-o, se não o crie).

Comment: E é possível fazer um loop no proprio código de inserção da marca d'água ? Para que ele mesmo sobreponha os .png ? Assim eu só precisaria por o avatar de cada cidade como Salvador, Brisas, Pontes e PortoVelho e o próprio usuário poderia gerar a sua imagem final com diversas possibilidades

Comment: Sim, isso é possível. Mas, tem esse porém. Salve a cada 'junção' e carregue. Exemplo: S + B = SB.png  | SB.png + P = SBP.png (este contém as 3). Agora, não sei como estão as imagens nem como está feito. Mas já fiz algo similar desta forma.

Comment: é.. nessa parte eu já fico perdido